# Locked write, unlocked read

Tags: c++, multithreading

**Algorithmic question**

How to allow only the following types of threaded operations on an object?

- multiple simultaneous reads, no writes
- single write, no reads

Example: wrapper for STL container allowing efficient search from multiple threads. For simplicity, let assume no iterator can be accessed from outside of the wrapper in question.

Let's assume we have semaphores and mutexes at out disposal.

I know that boost libraries has this concept implemented. I'd like to understand how is this usually done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [boost::shared_mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex) to handle frequent read, infrequent write access patterns.

As you've noted, STL containers are 'leaky' in that you can retrieve an iterator which has to be treated as either an implicit ongoing operation for write (if non-const) or read (if const), until the iterator goes out of scope.  Writes to the container by other threads while you hold such an iterator can invalidate it.  Your wrapper would have to be carefully designed to handle this case and keep the wrapper class efficient.

Comment: Boost is great, but I'd like to know an algorithm behind it. I've mentioned iterators problem in the last part of the question.

Comment: The code behind `shared_mutex` is platform-dependent.  On Windows it's extremely efficient, cannot speak to other platforms.

Comment: Wow, are algorithms there platform dependent too?

Comment: Yes, any locking code will be platform-dependent.  Boost provides a convenient abstraction that is not platform-dependent, and saves you getting the semantics right all over again by yourself. If you want to understand the logic you can look at platform-dependent code in the Boost download to compare the implementations.

Comment: I asking about concept, not about the code. An algorithm is a sequence of atomic operations in mathematical sense. I believe it should not be platform dependent.

Comment: Yes I just edited my comment.  You can understand the design from the code, yes?

Comment: Ok, I'll ask you again if there is something I can't understand from the boost code.

Comment: Btw the Windows code uses compare-and-swap (Interlocked* in Win32) to atomically check if a lock is available and set it if so, and resorts to a pair of Semaphores to control signalling if lock needs to be waited for.

Answer (score 1):

You want a "multiple-reader / single-writer" mutex : [Boost.Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.shared_mutex) provides one.